# String reading issue using scanf

Tags: c, input, scanf

Now i read somehwere:

> The scanf() conversion %[\n] will
>   match a newline character, while
>   %[^\n] will match all characters up to
>   a newline.

But in the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main() {
printf("Enter Something: ");
char name[100];   
scanf("%99[help]", name);
printf("%s",name);
}
```

I face no problem when i enter `help me` as the printed word is `help`. However when i enter `I need help` it prints garbage. Please help how to fix this problem?
My target is to match the word `help` entered anywhere along the input, e.g.,

```
"This is a test, i need help in this"
```

Should detect `help`.

Comment: That you can write `%[\n]` doesn't automatically mean you can write `%[help]`. You're leaping to conclusions and making assumptions: not good in programming! (I'm not even convinced that it's valid for `\n`.) What are you _actually_ trying to achieve here?

Comment: I am talking about pattern matching.

Comment: @NabinSur: What are you _actually_ trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the result of `scanf`. If it fails to match, the pointer you pass in is not modified. In your specific case, `name` would then contain arbitrary data.

Once you check the output of `scanf`, you'll see it's failing to match on that string. `scanf` is not a regular expression parser. It will only attempt a match on the first "item" it sees on the input stream.

The match specifier `%99[help]` means "i want to match anything that contains the letters h, e, l, p **in any order**, up to 99 chars long". That's all. So it fails on the very first letter of your input ("T"), which is not in the set.

If you want to look for a string inside another string, use `strstr` for example. To read a whole line, if your environment has it, the easiest is to use `getline`.

Answer (score 1):

You need the scanset to recognize all the characters you might enter.  You also need to check the return from `scanf()` to see whether it succeeded.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Enter Something: ");
    char name[100];   
    if (scanf("%99[Indhelp ]", name) != 1)
        fprintf(stderr, "scanf() failed\n");
    else
        printf("%s",name);
    return 0;
}
```

That will recognize "I need help" and many other phrases.  The C standard says:

> If a - character is in the scanlist and is not the first, nor the
>   second where the first character is a ^, nor the last character, the behavior is
>   implementation-defined.

In many implementations, you can use a notation such as `%[a-zA-Z ]` to pick up a string of letters or spaces.  However, that is implementation-defined behaviour.  That means it could do anything the implementation chooses, but the implementation must document what it does mean.

The reliable way to write the scanset is:

```
%[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ]
```

Of course, that leaves you with some issues around punctuation, not to mention accented characters; you can add both to the scanset if you wish.